# First argument is expected to be a valid callback for cp_admin_init and _canonical_charset

Tags: plugins, login, theme-twenty-eleven, callbacks, warnings

I'm using **WordPress 3.5** with child-theme of **Twenty Eleven 1.5**. Suddenly I'm getting following Warning,

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'cp_admin_init' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, '_canonical_charset' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173
```

I'm using following plugins:

- download-manager 2.3.9
- wordpress-seo 1.4.7
- wp-pagenavi 2.83

Some more points:

1) If I'm giving *mysite.com* it's giving above 2 line warning. If I give *www.mysite.com*,
the following line also include,

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

2) If I give *mysite.com/wp-admin/* or *www.mysite.com/wp-admin/*, It's giving 1st warning and 3rd warning.

3) If I goto *www.mysite.com/wp-login.php*, It's giving following 5 warning.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'cp_admin_init' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, '_canonical_charset' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-login.php on line 368

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-login.php on line 380

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'wp_authenticate_spam_check' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173
```

4) If I give correct username and password, it's not going to login. giving following problem,

```
ERROR: Invalid username or incorrect password.
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.
```

I'm trying to find solution. I can't. Can any-one help me?

Comment: While I don't want to frighten you, things rarely just "suddenly" get weird. Chances are that someone has done something whether that be you, your host, or (worst case) a hacker. It could also be corrupt files from a failed update or hardware failure. The first thing you should do is contact your host, and seriously consider a complete, thorough update of the site.

Comment: How I can update without login?

Comment: The only way you should be updating, in my opinion, [(s)FTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update).